# Problem connecting spotify APIS using StringRequest

Tags: android, spotify

I'm trying to connect my android app to Spotify APIS.
Now I'm able to login, and play some random music with URL songs. My problem is I'm not able to connect using GET. And my only one response is:

> E/Volley: [7721] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLline,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                parseData(response);
                System.out.println("respuesta: " + response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Accept", "application/json");
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        params.put("Authorization", "Bearer BQCljGDNl4xBRbSnJgl8O8tZU-OUIGGpBFsYZTD_QxcrHI-JN8-cFbfiewHTmSIlzMMuvRaX5lsPtDFwFsx_pNq37DEH8jll8sd9jXs6gPXGGTON0LOlzbzPXhAVz6mG_Ta-6BakiVo5C-MAjVL8UC9r9Hl8xIR_en9-tmpfCTKccEKI");
        return params;
    }

};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are sending the headers as GET parameters, you should override getHeaders().

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("xxx", "xxx");

            return params;  
    }
```